# How to push content down with position absolute in an horizontal menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want this menu: [Horizontal drop down menu](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/05/horizontal-drop-down-menu/comment-page-1/#comments) to push o move the content down, is it possible? Because when I change the position to relative (it pushes) in the "submenu" , the tags a's don´t continue in the same line as the example. Help would be appreciate.

Comment: Can you please show the code of the menu instead of providing a link? We'll like to see what *you* did, not the example.

Comment: It's very possible, and there's more than one way to make it work. You need to show us what you've done so far, and where exactly you're stuck - the community can help at that point.

Comment: I don't feel like reading through the entire code, but I think you can probably add a large `margin-bottom` to the navbar when the menu is open.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to something like this to the HTML structure.

```
<menu>
    <ul>
        <!-- main menu -->
    </ul>
</menu>
<nav>
    <!-- sub navigation -->
</nav>
<main>
    <!-- your content -->
</main>
```

Each element inside the menu would need to correspond to an element in the sub navigation.  You could do this with ids and data attributes.

```
//in main menu
<li data-menu="downloads"></li>

//in sub navigation
<div id="downloads"></div>
```

Then the javascript would listen to a click event in the main menu, and then show the correct sub navigation.  If you click a main menu item twice, it should close the sub navigation panel.  Here's jQuery to make it easy to read:

```
$('menu').on('click', 'li', function(){
   //get the id of the li
   var id = $(this).attr('data-menu');
   //select the correct element and check it's current visibility
   var navigation = $('#' + id);
   var isHidden = navigation.is(':hidden'); //returns true or false
   //close all navigation items
   $('nav').children('div').hide();
   //if the navigation item was hidden, show it
   if(isHidden){navigation.show()};
});
```

Just as an aside, jQuery 3.0 `.show()` and `.hide()` do different things than just toggle `display:none;`